# Catel IsDirty Not Bubbling Up ChildAwareModelBase

Tags: c#, catel

I am having trouble with Catel's `ChildAwareModelBase` `IsDirty` propety not bubbling up to the parent. I thought this worked for me in the past, but it is not functional in my current project and a sample project I just made. I have 3 objects: `Parent`, `Child`. and `GrandChild`. Heirarchy: Parent -> Child -> GrandChild. Each of the objects have a single property `Name`.

My expectation is that when I update `child.Name` then `parent.IsDirty` will be set to true. When I update `grandChild.Name` then both `parent.IsDirty` & `child.IsDirty` to be true. However, this does not happen. If I update `parent.Name` then `parent.IsDirty` is true.

What am I doing wrong? Sample project code is below.

FYI: I've tried removing `PropertyChanged.Fody` attribute and replacing the properties with Catels property implementation with the same result:

```cs
public string Name
{
    get { return GetValue<string>(NameProperty); }
    set { SetValue(NameProperty, value); }
}
 
public static readonly PropertyData NameProperty = RegisterProperty("Name", typeof(string), includeInBackup: false);
```

Sample Code:

```cs
using Catel.Data;

/*
 * Packages:
 *  Catel.MVVM (5.10.0)
 *  PropertyChanged.Fody (4.1.0)
 */

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Base model with clear dirty function.
    /// </summary>
    [PropertyChanged.AddINotifyPropertyChangedInterface]
    public class ModelBase : ChildAwareModelBase
    {
        public void ClearDirtyFlag()
        {
            IsDirty = false;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Parent object with 1 child and name property.
    /// </summary>
    [PropertyChanged.AddINotifyPropertyChangedInterface]
    class Parent : ModelBase
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public Child Child { get; set; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// First child of the parent.
    /// </summary>
    [PropertyChanged.AddINotifyPropertyChangedInterface]
    class Child : ModelBase
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public GrandChild GrandChildOfParent { get; set; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Grand child of the parent.
    /// </summary>
    [PropertyChanged.AddINotifyPropertyChangedInterface]
    class GrandChild : ModelBase
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var parent = new Parent();
            var child = new Child();
            var grandChild = new GrandChild();

            parent.Child = child;
            child.GrandChildOfParent = grandChild;

            parent.ClearDirtyFlag();
            child.ClearDirtyFlag();
            grandChild.ClearDirtyFlag();

            var dirtyCheckParent0 = parent.IsDirty;
            
            child.Name = "dfd";
            var dirtyCheckParent1 = parent.IsDirty;
            
            parent.Name = "dfd";
            var dirtyCheckParent2 = parent.IsDirty;


            Console.ReadLine();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why use PropertyChanged.Fody? It's recommended to use Catel.Fody instead.